# C# + Access Error: Not a valid File name

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

It seems that there's a problem with my file directory. I learned from 1 post here in Stack Overflow that there is a hidden [enter] or \n in the directory of my file. I don't understand it. Here is my code

My connection string:

```
    con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪C:\CRDB\crdb.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
```

and here is what I'm doing:

```
public void loadTable()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
                com.Connection = con;
                string query = "SELECT * FROM ChequeMasterList";
                com.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                con.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

As you can see it is very simple. I just want to load my database onto my Datagridview, but i keep on getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEZMc.png)

I've been doing a lot of C# systems nowadays and this is the first time i ran into this problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your Access DB is not where you think it is, or something has it locked making it inaccessible.  Make sure you are building to 32 bit, and don't run code in the Load event — use a constructor.

Comment: @LarsTech What do you mean something has it locked? hmm... how can that happen? and also what do you mean building to 32 bit? Sorry, all these terms seems new to me. I'm a casual programmer and only do this as a hobby.

Comment: @LarsTech I've tried to use the default path of Access which is in my Documents, but still got the same error. Tried renaming the folder and the file, still the same error. I also tried to change the location of my database, but still got the same error. Please help.

Comment: Access is usually a 32 bit database, so you have to match it: Properties - Build - Platform target: x86.  Having your Access database opened exclusively by Access the program is one way the database could be locked.  I'm just throwing out suggestions.  `C:\CRDB\crdb.accdb` has to exist and you have to have permissions for it.  That's not a normal file path in today's environment.

Comment: click the start button and enter C:\CRDB\crdb.accdb and see if you can open it that way. Another option could be to rename the database and change your connection string to match the new name and see if that works. If it does, you should then be able to rename it back and fix your connection string and try again with that.

Comment: @LarsTech it does exist. how come i dont have permissions for it?

Comment: @CharlesMay i could open it by typing `C:\CRDB\crdb.accdb` in start. Also tried renaming the database, but still got the same error.

Comment: I tried to create a new project to test the connection between c# and access with just a label. the instruction was to change the `label1.Text` to `"connected"` between the `con.Open();` and `con.Close();`. It seems to work. hmm, now I'm guessing that there's nothing wrong with my connection string, but where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Tried to recreate the instruction stated above on the newly created project to test the connection and everything was okay. what is wrong? lol! I guess I'll try to recreate the whole project step by step and test everything along the way. If you have a better Idea please do comment it or add an answer below. I will not delete the old project since it's easier just to fix that if there's a solution than to create a new one from scratch.

Comment: @DanArenas See http://ideone.com/j4Ps46

Answer (score 0):

The escape code \c is illegal in a file name. Use \\c and \\C. Your quoted string is not what you think it is.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it. What escape code? What should my path look like?

Comment: I did a little research, im still not sure if I'm doing it right. I've changed my path to `C:\CRDB\\crdb` and still got the same error. please do correct me if I'm wrong. thanks.

Comment: I'm truly not certain if this answer is the actual issue (new to c# and the way literal strings work myself) but did you try it with the following connection string: `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪C:\\CRDB\\crdb.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;"` and also maybe the same thing without the @ in front of it?

Comment: @DanArenas See ideone.com/j4Ps46

Comment: @CharlesMay I tried. i got the same error. I think my project is somewhat the problem. I've decided to create a new project and everything was running smoothly. I dont know what happened but there was not error on the new one despite having the same code.